# Photoshop multiple color filters

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, filters

Can anyone share how to do this lighting effect in Photoshop as a post-process?
[image]

**Solved**

1. Blur image
2. Color filter the whole image yellow hue
3. Add opaque paintbrush layers (with huge brush) for blue and purple colors
4. Touch-ups/details

Comment: Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions . Also, that is a creepy image!

Comment: Yes, please do add more text description to the question — it'll help search later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious Lens Blur it looks like it was overlayed with a Gradient Fill layer using a custom color gradient, or the overlay could have been a layer containing a few coarse color splotches: yellowish on bottom, bluish left, and purplish right.

Answer (score 1):

This image may actually feature very little Photoshop or post-processing from any computer software at all. It may simply be taken with lights gelled to the appropriate color, and with the lens defocused.

Comment: Or even with various colors of Vaseline on different parts of the front of the lens (or on a filter).